# Unhandled promise rejection InvalidStateError ReactJS and Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am using ReactJS and loading an HTML 5 video on my web page.

I keep getting the following error in IE 10 and lower when the page loaded:

```
Unhandled promise rejection InvalidStateError
"Unhandled promise rejection"
```

Apparently IE 10 is throwing the error here:

```
   componentDidMount() {
     document.getElementById('video').currentTime = this.props.currentVideoFramePosition;
   }


   componentDidMount() {
     document.getElementById('video').currentTime = this.props.currentVideoFramePosition;
   }

  render(){
    const videoUrl = this.props.videoUrl;
    return(
      <div>
            <div className="framegrab-videocontainer">
              <img src="/assets/images/arrow_left_grab.svg" className="arrow-left" onClick={() => this.onArrowNavClick(-1)}></img>
              <video id="video" src={videoUrl} className="framegrab-video" controls crossOrigin="anonymous" onPause={e => this.draw()} onSeeked={e => this.draw()} />
              <img src="/assets/images/arrow_right_grab.svg" className="arrow-right"  onClick={() => this.onArrowNavClick(1)}></img>
            </div>
        </div>
        );
  }
```